# Stuck at connecting MySQL using the Connector/c++. driver->connect("localhost", "user", "password") throwing bad::alloc error

Tags: c++, mysql, database

I've set up everything as the documentation guides but when I try to execute the file it keeps throwing an exception at the

> con = driver->connect(url, user, password);

Here's the code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <memory>
#include <mysql/jdbc.h>

int main(string args[]) {
    //MySql variables for connecting to the database
    
    sql::Driver* driver;
    sql::Connection* con;

    const sql::SQLString url = "tcp://127.0.0.1:3306";
    const sql::SQLString user = "root";
    const sql::SQLString password = "******";
    const sql::SQLString schema = "opencvdb";

    driver = get_driver_instance();
    con = driver->connect(url, user, password); // error
    con->setSchema(schema);
    return 0;
}
```

any help would be valuable, I tried a lot of solutions for hours

Comment: Unhandled exception at 0x00007FFB921F4B89 in OpenCV.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: std::bad_alloc at memory location 0x00000027F595D030.

Comment: Why not working with SQLite which is available for C++?

Comment: I rather use mysql for practicing matters.

Comment: You have a bad allocation at that line; I think you have to setup ```con``` before you call ```connect```

Comment: *con* is already set up you can see it before the const variables definition.